# How do I get Bundler to consider local gems as "already installed"?

Tags: ruby, bundler

I'm developing two Ruby gems simultaneously, one of which depends on the other. Say my gem names are "foo" and "bar". "bar" depends on "foo", so its gemspec includes this:

```
s.add_runtime_dependency "foo", "~> 0"
# More dependencies...
```

And my Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gemspec
```

Of course, running `bundle install` now will give me an error since "foo" is placed in a local folder.

I don't want to comment out the dependency line, nor do I want to point it to a local folder, because that would be a local change that I would *never* commit to my Git repo. It would be taking up space under `git status` and it would be in the way when I need to make modifications to the file.

I'm hoping there are some tricks I can do with some environment variables that will let Bundler know where "foo" is, and count it as "already installed". Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This trick is done using bundler.

Let's say that gem *foo* depends upon gem *bar*.  Then in foo's Gemfile, use bundler's *path* option to point to gem *bar*:

```
gem "bar", path: "/home/wayne/lab/bar"
```

then `bundle install`

After that, commands such as `bundle exec rspec`, `bundle exec rake features`, etc., will use the gem "bar" out of your local folder.

When done, revert the `gem "bar"` line in Gemfile to its normal form.

---

If you want to keep the Gemfile modification permanently, you have several options.  One is to just check it in with the modification.  According to the [Gemfile source priority](http://bundler.io/man/gemfile.5.html#SOURCE-PRIORITY), Bundler will first try to load the gem from the local path, then fall back to installing it from the global source.

If the gem is public, your local modification might be confusing to someone who clones your gem.  In that case, since a Gemfile is just ruby code, you can use, for example, an environment variable to turn on your location modification:

```
# When making concurrent modifications to gem "bar",
# use that gem by its local directory.
if ENV['BAR_GEM_PATH']
  gem "bar", path: ENV['BAR_GEM_PATH']
end
```

Comment: That's neat, but it still means I have to have local modifications that I'll never commit, which I'd like to avoid. If I were okay with that, I could just remove the "foo" line altogether, then bundler wouldn't complain when installing the dependencies.

Comment: Elaborated a bit more in my question now.

Comment: Ok, this question is a bit wrong. I don't actually have to remove the `path:` option, and I can safely commit it. According to the [Gemfile source priority](http://bundler.io/man/gemfile.5.html#SOURCE-PRIORITY), Bundler will *first* try to load the gem from the local path, then fall back to installing it from the global source. You should probably edit that into your answer.

Comment: @Hubro That's good to know.  I don't want to recommend it, though: I don't think it's good to publish what should be a local, temporary modification to the Gemfile.

Comment: It's not exactly temporary though. It will probably be needed for the entire lifetime of the project.

Comment: @Hubro Is the gem private, or public?

Comment: They are private, but even if they weren't, the `path:` option would still be needed for as long as the gems are being developed together.

Comment: @Hubro Private is a whole different matter.  I did fold your research, and an idea using environment variables, into the answer.

Comment: Nice idea. I'm going with `if Dir.exist? "../foo"`.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it in .gemspec, please put it like following code

```
gem 'gem_name', path: 'full/path/to/your_gem'
```

in my exp, it's best way to dev two gem at same time, if you upload one gem to rubygems.org, you can use `s.add_runtime_dependency "foo", "~> 0"`, but if you wanna change gem "foo" code, and upadate in another proj, you need to run `bundle install` again. it's very waste time to do that.

Comment: Yeah, that's not a viable solution. Project "bar" must always have the newest development version of "foo" while I'm working, so releasing the gem for every small file change is out of the question.